# Does WordPress have an Browser Agent?

Tags: plugin-development

I want to block a directory to everyone but WordPress's internal upgrade feature (I am trying to get WordPress to do auto-updates of my premium plugin). I have it updating, but I really would like to block the directory for everyone but WordPress. Anyone know what WP's internal User Agent is?

Comment: Planning to do an .htaccess block if that matters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WordPress user agent is set in the class `WP_Http` as

```
'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . get_bloginfo( 'url' )
```

You can set it to a (secret) fixed value per filter:

```
add_filter( 'http_headers_useragent', 'wpse_59788_user_agent' );
function wpse_59788_user_agent()
{
    // to remove this filter immediately uncomment the following line
    // remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return 'alfgjlkgjlkgjsldkjhrkjh';
}
```

To change the user agent for a plugin upgrade only try something like this (not tested):

```
add_filter( 'upgrader_pre_install', 'wpse_59788_register' );
function wpse_59788_register( $dummy )
{
    add_filter( 'http_headers_useragent', 'wpse_59788_user_agent' );
    return $dummy;
}
```

And uncomment the self deactivation line in the first function.

Comment: Is this value now used in all outgoing requests to other servers then or do I need to edit the requests as well?

Comment: Depends on how you use the filter. You could activate it for your personal updates only and deactivate it when the request is done.

Comment: Lets say I do this:
add_filter(headers)  
update_function(); deregister_filter(header), the update function will use the UA automatically?

Comment: @chriscct7 I made an update to my answer.